# Convert pdf to a different page size (US Letter -> A4)

Tags: printing, pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to print a simple US Letter document, but for some reason, I just cannot manage to fit it properly onto A4 when printing multiple pages per-list.

I have tried converting the pdf using:
`gs -o print.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -pPDFFitPage -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 input.pdf`

But this does not seem to have any effect on the document, it still shows as US letter.

Any way how to convert a pdf to A4 format?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446552/resizing-a-pdf-using-ghostscript which does not depend on a LaTeX installation.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

One solution that usually works is to use `pdfjam` from the texlive distribution

```
> pdfinfo in.pdf 
...
Producer:       Acrobat Distiller 6.0.1 (Windows)
...
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot:       0
File size:      66676 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.4

> pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --paper a4paper in.pdf

> pdfinfo out.pdf 
Creator:        TeX
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.15
...
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
File size:      53963 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

Setting the paper size to something unconventional works with another switch, such as `--papersize '{6.125in,9.250in}'`.

As you can see here it also changed the PDF version, and dropped/modified other properties of the PDF, so you have to check if its suitable for your task.

Comment: Tried to use this on a PDF document with forms. As a result I lost the forms and the saved data.

Comment: pdfjam does not work with encrypted PDF files, and does not preserve hyperlinks.