# How to resize a PDF's pages?

Tags: pdf

I got a PDF file for which I want to change its pages' sizes; let's call it `file.pdf`. And I got another PDF file which will serve as the model to `file.pdf`; let's call it `model.pdf`.

To clarify: I want `file.pdf`'s pages to be of equal measure as `model.pdf`'s pages.

Using `pdfinfo` on `model.pdf` I get the following relevant info:

```
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          22
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 783 pts
Page rot:       0
MediaBox:           0.00     0.00   720.00   891.00
CropBox:           54.00    54.00   666.00   837.00
BleedBox:          54.00    54.00   666.00   837.00
TrimBox:           54.00    54.00   666.00   837.00
ArtBox:            54.00    54.00   666.00   837.00
File size:      3324788 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.7
```

I don't really understand what the first two columns of the `*Box` fields mean, but doing some Googling I got to the conclusion that my target are the last two columns of the `MediaBox` field. So, I want `file.pdf` to be `720x891`, and I think the units are `pts`.

So I found this tool called `pdfposter` which is supposed to be able to change the size of a PDF's pages, and I did this (noteice I already made the conversion from points to inches):

```
pdfposter -m10x12.375inch file.pdf new_file.pdf
```

Everything goes well, but when I check `new_file.pdf` with `pdfinfo` I get:

```
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          32
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      630.22 x 891 pts
Page rot:       0
MediaBox:          54.33    32.60   774.33   923.60
CropBox:           54.33    32.60   684.55   923.60
BleedBox:          54.33    32.60   684.55   923.60
TrimBox:           54.33    32.60   630.22   891.00
ArtBox:            54.33    32.60   630.22   891.00
File size:      3005203 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

Clearly something went wrong since the size of the new PDF's pages is `774.33x923.60` and not `720x891`; moreover, the first two columns of the `MediaBox` changed from `0.00 0.00` to `54.33 32.60` and I got no idea why or what it means.

I also tried using `pdfjam` but it just adds more white space to the borders, while leaving the content of the PDF untouched.

So my question is: how can I change the size of my `file.pdf`'s pages to that of `model.pdf`.

**Note:** It is very important for me that the resized PDF be of the same quality as the original PDF.

Comment: I tested and had trouble with the answer below, but then found this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185224/188451 which uses pdfjam, fantastic. Yes, is not exactly the same as what the OP here was asking but is a very good solution for that kind of issue.

Comment: 4 years later I find myself commenting on the same post, still resizing and merging pdfs from the terminal... Usually I don't need to resize, but this time, the following ghostscript command did the trick - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28455147/4288043

Answer (score 9):

You can use pdfjam with the `--papersize` argument to set the output paper size. You may also need to use `--scale` and `--offset` if you want to do more than resize the page and its contents together.

```
pdfjam --papersize="$(LC_ALL=C pdfinfo model.pdf | LC_ALL=C awk '/^Page size:/ {printf "{%fbp,%fbp}", $3, $5}')" file.pdf new_file.pdf
```

Comment: Beware that the `--papersize` format, `"{XXu,YYu}"`, is quite strict : single or double quotes, braces, comma and units are all mandatory.

Comment: This is the command that worked for me: `pdfjam --papersize '{8.3in,11.7in}' Input.pdf --outfile Output.pdf` -- A4 page size

Answer (score 3):

You could try using ghostscript, which has a zillion options, including settings the output size in points:

```
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage \
    -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=720 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=891 -dBATCH \
    -dSAFER file.pdf
```

Not sure if you want `-dPDFFitPage` or not, but you can try it both with and without.

Answer (score -2):

`ps2pdf` with ebook-settings had very good results for me, e.g. reducing a pdf from an image scan from 3 MB to 150 kB.

```
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook input.pdf output.pdf
```