# Copy machine refuses my pdf

Tags: pdf, printing, printer, ghostscript

I regularly need to convert pdf document in A4 format into US letter format.
Following [Convert pdf to a different page size (US Letter -> A4)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185145/101324), I use

```
pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --paper letter in.pdf
```

to do so.

**However, my pdf, which seems perfectly fine on my computer, cannot be printed on my copy machine.**

I transfer the pdf to an usb stick, load it in the copy machine (a bizhub C652), the copy machine sees the file just fine, but refuses to print it.
Following the same routine, I can print any pdf files.

Is the pdf not perfectly compatible, in some way? The original, A4 file, reads just fine on the copy machine, but cannot be printed, due to the lack of A4 paper.

In the [bizhub C652 manual](ftp://207.18.56.26/software/BPG/bizhubC452_C552_C552DS_C652_C652DSPrint_Fax_Scan_BoxOperationsQuickGuide.pdf), no recommendation or specification whatsoever is made about the format of the document printed [in the Section "Printing a document in external memory"](ftp://207.18.56.26/software/BPG/bizhubC452_C552_C552DS_C652_C652DSPrint_Fax_Scan_BoxOperationsQuickGuide.pdf#G3.1529443).

Comment: @JJoao I'd be extremely surprised if this was the case. The original file does not have this restriction, I don't see why pdfjam would add it.

Comment: It's hard to debug your copy machine from here. There could be many reasons like "margins too small" or uncomplete pdf implementation or missing fonts or whatever. Is this "refusing" connected to any error message?

Comment: @Philippos I know, but anything that could help me understanding this error would help. No, no error message whatsoever is displayed.